# Windows 10 search doesn't find links or portable apps

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, cortana

I am new to Windows 10 and did a fresh install of the pro version. I disabled Cortana because I didn't want all my personal information going to Microsoft. But now, Windows search will not find portable applications or links on my desktop. Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: I have this issue on four diffent computers and havent found a solution. Windows 10 dosent seem to find any exe files. E.g. create a txt on the desktop and search for it. You will find it. Create a exe file on the deskop and search for it, windows 10 doesent find that file. If there is any solution i would be very glad. I allready tested a lot and didnt find a solution for this issue.